# Leaflet Routing Machine routing icons are not displaying correctly!

Tags: leaflet, routing

I'm having an issue with the routing icons in Leaflet Routing Machine. For some reason that I can't figure out, the only icon that is displayed is the up arrow icon, regardless if the router says to turn left, right, or etc. I've followed the specifications and still am having this issue.

Any clues as to what could be the cause?

Here are some screenshots to display my issue:

[image]
[image]